# can I add a subdomain through my web host if the domain is hosted through another registrar

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, subdomain, domain-registrar

I have a domain that is registered through a registrar to whom I don't have access. I want to create a subdomain through the hosting environment, to which I do have access. Is this possible?

Comment: where are the DNS server handling your domain? with you or does the registrar host your DNS as well?

Comment: How is this off topic? "Questions on Server Fault are expected to relate to professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hostname <--> IP address mapping is done by the nameservers, which probably are handled by your registrar (but you'd have to check if the nameserver for your domain is handled by your hosting provider). If `subdomain.your.domain.here` isn't registered at the nameservers, if somebody tries to contact `subdomain.your.domain.here` they'll just be told politely that that site doesn't exist, whatever you do locally. Running `dig -t ns your.domain.here` will tell you the names of the nameservers, and that could help you figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the server that the site is running on?  You should be able to set up an Apache vhost to handle the hostname requests, but if you mean something like shop.mysite.com and you can't access the registrar for mysite.com, then i think you're out of luck without something like a domain transfer.   Do you have access to the DNS server that points to the site?  A CNAME record would create a subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

if your domain is set up in such way, that every subdomain forwards to your domain (for example, if anything.yourdomain.com is redirected to your hosting at yourdomain.com) then you can simply define few rules in .htaccess file to handle subdomain requeste (if you are allowed to have custom .htaccess...)